# Could not find com.android.support:design:23.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I couldn't compile my android project and I can't find out why. By the way, the project compiled successfully on another computer.
This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iba.navdrawer"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

And this is stack trace:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. Could not resolve
>   all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'. Could not
>   find com.android.support:design:23.0.1.
>
> ```
>  Searched in the following locations:
>      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.0.1/design-23.0.1.pom
>      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/23.0.1/design-23.0.1.jar
>      file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.0.1/design-23.0.1.pom
>      file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.0.1/design-23.0.1.jar
>      file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.0.1/design-23.0.1.pom
>      file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.0.1/design-23.0.1.jar
>  Required by:
>      NavDrawer:app:unspecified
> ```
>
> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0.
>
> ```
>  Searched in the following locations:
>      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.3.0/play-services-maps-8.3.0.pom
>      https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.3.0/play-services-maps-8.3.0.jar
>      file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.3.0/play-services-maps-8.3.0.pom
>      file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.3.0/play-services-maps-8.3.0.jar
>      file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.3.0/play-services-maps-8.3.0.pom
>      file:/C:/Program Files/Android/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-maps/8.3.0/play-services-maps-8.3.0.jar
>  Required by:
>      NavDrawer:app:unspecified
> ```

And this is my sdk manager:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You basically posted the answer yourself. Update all of the tools that need to be updated. Also the latest version of the Support library is `23.1.1`.

Comment: Check if offlineMode is disabled in android studio gradle build settings

Comment: @JaredBurrows, but why can't I compile with these tools? The version of used sdk and Android Support Library is 23. Why then android studio can't find `com.android.support:design:23.0.1`?

Comment: You need to update the support repositories so Gradle can find it and add it. As I said in my previous comment, update all of the tools/repositories/libraries it is asking you to update.

Comment: I'll try it. But I can't understand how it concerns the issue...

Comment: @JaredBurrows, I updated all except Support Repository and this now this error gone. But I can't understand why.

Comment: The "libraries" are downloaded as jars locally and the "repositories" are locall maven repositories that Gradle can "download" from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is.You are using: **23.0.1**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

which you've downloaded the **23.1.1** and the gradle couldn't find it.

**Use:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

or you should download the previous version for using.

**Also, remember you need to update your Support Repository for finding the packages on Android Studio**

and of course, for now, seems like the best way is Updating all packages on `SDK Manager`

Comment: In this case I get the same error:
Could not find com.android.support:design:23.1.1

Comment: @LinX64, Gradle could not find it, not the IDE. And it is not a version issue. Ksenia does not have the repository.

Comment: @LinX64 Once again, this is not an IDE issue. The IDE uses Gradle. Gradle can't find the dependnecies. Ksenia needs to update everything in the SDK manager.

Comment: @LinX64, I updated all except Support Repository and this now this error gone. But I can't understand why.

Comment: @Ksenia For understanding why that error gone, Support Repository is just like checking the packages with the repository which we need to keep it always update. That's what I've figured out.

Comment: @JaredBurrows You're right, I've fixed the type mistake. Thank you :)